# Package like combinat

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, combinatorica

I started using Mathematica and want to do some computation involving Characters of the symmetric group. In maple, I used to use the package combinat. The link is below 
https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=combinat

Which have partition function, Character of the symmetric group and things? I wonder what would be an equivalent package for Mathematica? I am sure it should exist but could not find it for now.

What I am particularly looking is to work with the symmetric group $S_n$. Conjugancy classes of $S_n$ are given by partition, so I want to evaluate the Char on some conjugancy class. In maple it is

Char([],[])
[] represent partition for integer n.

So I want to ask the community.

Comment: [This guide](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/GroupTheory.html) might be helpful. But the built-in group-theoretic capabilities are indeed somewhat limited.

Comment: Maybe it is also possible to call [Gap](https://www.gap-system.org) from Mathematica; check [this link](https://www.gap-system.org/ForumArchive/Egner.1/Sebastia.1/[Mathema.1/1.html). This "package" was written for Mathematica 2, though. Quite unlikely that it will work with modern versions.

Comment: You can get character tables of the symmetric groups using FiniteGroupData[{"SymmetricGroup", 6}, "CharacterTable"] for example. The table is sorted following IntegerPartitions[6].